# Getting undefined when trying to get json data from other domain

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, cross-domain

I need to read json data from this url https://api.intelligentsolution.com.ve/inmobiliar/api/Propiedades/tasacion

but I'm always getting an undefined value

Even when I can see the json data in the response through the developer tools. For some reason I can't print it or use it as I want to

```
function print(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.intelligentsolution.com.ve/inmobiliar/api/Propiedades/tasacion',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonpCallback: print,
  jsonp: 'callback',
});
```

Comment: That API doesn't support JSONP, only JSON. You'll need to call it from the server, not the client.

Comment: is there a way I can do it from the client? need to do it in this case

Comment: Not if the API doesn't support CORS.

Comment: Why do you need to do it? Why can't you use a proxy on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Since you insist on making the request only from the client-side you could use third party API that enables cross-origin requests to anywhere.

**Here's the code:**

```
function print(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

$.ajax({
  // using third party API https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/
  url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.intelligentsolution.com.ve/inmobiliar/api/Propiedades/tasacion',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: print,
  error: function() {
    console.log('Unable to complete the request');
  }
});
```